# Putting all const values of a class in the same place

Tags: c++, constants

I am trying to use some compile-time const values for a class  and I am using constexpr/const, but I dislike a lot the fact that some will be inited in the hpp and some in the .cpp.

I've read the explanation related to string incompatibility with constexpr, but
isn't a trick to put all of them in the same location?
It's strange that in the modern C++ 11/14 you have to declare them in two separate locations.:)
Thank you

```
// test.hpp
class Test
{
    // initialization values are located clear in the header
    static constexpr int a_{10};
    static constexpr int b_{20};

    // we must go to the cpp file to see this string value
    static const std::string str_;
};

// test.cpp
const std::string Test::str_{"abc"};
```

Comment: For what it's worth, even `a_` or `b_` will need definitions in a .cpp file if their address is ever taken (including being passed by reference). C++11 and C++14 introduced cool new stuff, but this particular issue has not changed. tl;dr: it's not possible.

Comment: This will remain a problem until the standard committee gets rid of the rule that you cannot use `new` at compile time. A workaround in this case should be to just replace `std::string` with `std::string_view`.

Comment: I just want to use them as read only (like C-style #defines) but it seems that it's not possible yet. Thanks guys.